# Full width of section and nav

Tags: css

Does anybody please have an idea why the header, nav and section are not at full width? As you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/v822x7gL/ there is still yellow space in the left and right side.

```
header {
      min-width:100%;
      float: left;
      height:70px;
      background-color:blue;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    nav {
      min-width:100%;
      float:left;
      height:50px;
      background-color:grey;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    nav li {
      display:inline; 
    }

    .victory_podium {
      min-width:100%;
      float:left;
      margin-top:20px;
      padding: 2% 5% 2% 5%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      background-color:red;
    }
```

Comment: the body element has a default margin applied. Remove it

Comment: Simply inspecting your document with your browser's tools would've told you the reason.

Answer (score 0):

simply you need margin:0px to body

```
body {
    background-color:yellow;
    margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue (btw. for j08691, I was trying to find out the reason via browser's tool but body element did not show me default margin)

Answer (score -1):

Now it works-ish:

http://jsfiddle.net/v822x7gL/

Try to use "Position":
 `margin: 0 auto;`

I hope this helps, if not try working your way though the code line by line.

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out right after I posted this. You just needed to change the css affecting the body with "margin: 0;" 
I did not see it before I posted it, so I made you something that worked, but could've been done a whole lot better with placing margin in body.